# official Stock api for stocks of Yahoo

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-api

You may find this question repost but none of them has satisfy answer.

I want to know what is the legal and supported stock fetching php api From YAHOO FINANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `YQL` - yahoo query language. (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

Eaxamples here -

```
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html
http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2009/06/02/getting-stock-information-with-yql-and-open-data-tables/
```

Comment: The OP wants something that is supported.

Comment: @salathe - i don't any reason why yahoo api won't be supported. It is an open, client facing api. All you would ever need is an private-key, which you can generate very easily. If you don't want to have a key, take a look at this link - http://goo.gl/iQ8ZZ

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. See http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Stock-Quote-API-returning-commas-in/1234765072000-6036c128-a7e0-3aa5-9e72-1af1871e1b41. Yahoo has clearly mention , he does not suport apis

Comment: @Pushpesh The CSV feed of stock information is not supported, nor even officially sanctioned for external use. See the discussion linked above.

Comment: I have asked on another thread also.Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256624/legal-php-yahoo-api-for-fetching-stock.   So will you think, Yahoo Query is official supported and legal to use in website ???????????????????